# Can I create Tuple without initialization?

Tags: tuples, d

I need to create Tuple. I do:

```
auto historyTuple = Tuple!(string, "gps", string, "sensor");
```

I want to initialize with data it's later.

I am getting error:

`Error: type Tuple!(string, "gps", string, "sensor") has no value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you specified on the right is actually the type of the tuple. You should instead write

```d
Tuple!(string, "gps", string, "sensor") historyTuple;
```

However, if you intend to use this tuple very often, you may instead wish to create an alias for it:

```d
alias History = Tuple!(string, "gps", string, "sensor");
History historyTuple;
```